# Interact with websites?

Tags: android

If i am developing a third party tool. is there a way to interact with that website?

For example i am making a android Application which allow the user to search a specific website. Is there possible to load the search result in listview?

This was just an example.

So get information from a website becuase i want a different layout and so on.

EDIT* and how do i do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Depends if you control the website, if that website has an api. Generally, there is always a way, it is merely a matter of how complicated it's going to be. Have any websites in mind?

Comment: Usally or in this case i am not the owner and have no access or contact with admin however i can see the source-code on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you want to display the content of your webpage in a specifically designed application you can use WebKit, the web engine inside android, in a WebView. Check more on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html) link.

2) If you want to have a more granular control over the data shared you can use the [apache http client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) to share data over http, and reformat it for the user. You can also set up customs http request between the terminal and your server to improve the mobile experience.